# setState method in ReactJS is not updating the fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After storing the data from controlled form element, I want to reset the value of my input type to empty.
In this method below setState is not setting it to empty. Not sure why.

```
 handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.dispatch(passengerActions.addPassenger(this.state.passenger));
        this.setState({ ...this.state.passenger, firstName: "", lastName: "" });
  };
```

The following method works

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch(passengerActions.addPassenger(this.state.passenger));
    const passenger = {
      ...this.state.passenger,
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
    };
    this.setState({ passenger });
};
```

Please help me understand why the first method is not working. I am new to ReactJS.

Comment: They don't do the same thing. It's not clear what you need the shape of your state to be, but the second example stores the new empty strings as `this.state.passenger.firstName` (etc), while the first does so directly at `this.state.firstName`

Comment: I will also note in passing that you shouldn't directly reference `this.state` in `setState`. You should pass it a function instead - see the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first one, you're spreading out your `passenger` object at the **top** level of your state, and adding `firstName` and `lastName` at the top level as well.

You probably wanted to update `passenger`, which is what you do in your second one:

```
this.setState({passenger: { ...this.state.passenger, firstName: "", lastName: "" }});
// −−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

**But**, whenever updating state based on existing state (the other fields in `passenger` you're copying over), it's usually best to use the callback form because state updates are asynchronous and can get batched together:

```
this.setState(({passenger}) => ({passenger: { ...passenger, firstName: "", lastName: "" }}));
```

Answer (score -1):

You should rewrite your 1st solution like:
this.setState({
  ...state,
  passenger: {
    firstName: “”,
    lastName: “”
  }
})

Comment: Assuming you meant `this.state`, not just `state`, this is poor practice, for at least a couple of reasons. One is that state updates are asynchronous and can be batched, so using the current state when setting may end up overwriting something that's been scheduled but not yet done. Also, React merges the object you get `setState` with the state anyway, so the `...state` above is not only not a good idea, but unnecessary. Finally, you're assuming in the above that `passenger` only has `firstName` and `lastName` fields, but given the OP's question, that seems unlikely.

Comment: @T.J Crowder - thanks for your info. Just to start, I was on my cellphone so didn’t ‘catch up’ that passenger had other fields than mentioned. And surely, thank you regarding the info you gave me, I will certainly have a look on that in documentation, seems like I misunderstood some concepts or at least didn’t use the best practices. So, thanks again for pointing me out!

Comment: No worries! Some of this stuff is tricky at first. :-) Happy coding! (You can delete the answer using the "delete" link under it -- which also gets you back the rep the downvote cost you.)

Comment: Haha I will think about it ;) Thanks once again!